# AdWords test with two different agencies - can I track their results without them being aware of each other

Tags: google, google-ads, ppc

I am currently going through a process of testing two AdWords PPC providers at the same time from two separate AdWords accounts. However they will require access to my GA account for linking and eCommerce tracking. Which means that they will be able to see each others results. I don't want this;

Is it possible to set up GA so that;

- Company A only sees Adwords results associated to their AdWords
  management via GA
- Company B only sees Adwords results associated to their
  AdWords management via GA

And each company never sees the other company's Adwords results?

Answer (score 2):

Google doesn't allow you to buy ads from multiple accounts for the same company, see their TOS:
http://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2600168

Sometimes this is allowed, but only in situations where the accounts are not advertising for the same terms in the same countries, etc

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to give them complete access to your GA account. You can limit what they have access to by creating a filtered profile.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsAccounts#filteredProfile

In addition to their TOS specifications as Jeremiah mentioned in his answer, I would suggest you have one company run their campaign first stop, then have the other company start. Inserting annotations in your GA before during after as needed etc for each campaign so you have some good data on who did better.

I would hurry though because were nearing the end of Oct and come Nov ecommerce traffic will increase across the board and possibly skew results. So maybe have each company run a week of PPC?